# How to find customer satisfaction using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns such as agent_email and effortscore. In effortscore, Y means dissatisfied and N means satisfied.

columns look like this:

```
agent_email effortscore.
ab           1
ab           0
xy           1
xy           0
```

---

```
formula=(total 1's / total response)*100.
```

I want the output to be like

```
ab 50% csat
xy 100% csat
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Comment: columns look like this:
agent_email effortscore
ab@gmail.com 1
ab@gmail.com 0
xy@gmail.com 1
xy@gmail.com 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need aggregate `mean`, it working, because only `1` and `0` values and number of `1` divided by total is `mean` formula:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'agent_email':['ab@gmail.com','ab@gmail.com','xy@gmail.com'],
                   'effortscore':[1,0,1]})

df1 = df.groupby('agent_email')['effortscore'].mean().mul(100).reset_index()
print (df1)
    agent_email  effortscore
0  ab@gmail.com         50.0
1  xy@gmail.com        100.0
```

Because data in question are different, need compare by `eq` for `==` and aggregate `mean`:

```
print (df)
  agent_email effortscore
0          ab           Y
1          ab           N
2          xy           Y
3          xy           N

df1 = df['effortscore'].eq('Y').groupby(df['agent_email']).mean().mul(100).reset_index()
print (df1)
  agent_email  effortscore
0          ab         50.0
1          xy         50.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is working perfectly and saved lot of my time. I was unnecessarily creating functions and loop to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas groupby and sum functions you can do this.

```
df2 = df.groupby('email').agg({'sat': ['sum','count']})

# flatten the structure of dataframe
df2.columns = ['_'.join(tup).rstrip('_') for tup in df2.columns.values]

# email out from index
df3=df2.reset_index()

# create new df based on calculated values
df3['csat']=df3.sat_sum/df3.sat_count*100
```